# syntax for declaring a function template

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I'm trying to create a template function that takes a vector argument of any type T (primitive for now) and prints out its contents:

```
template<class T>
void displayContents(const vector<T>& data)
{
    vector<T>::const_iterator i;
    i=data.begin();

    for( ; i!=data.end(); i++){
        cout<<*i<endl;
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> In function 'void displayContents(const std::vector >&)':
>   error: expected ';' before 'i' |
>   error:'i' was not declared in this scope
>   === Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===

Am I overlooking a syntax error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  typename vector<T>::const_iterator i;
```

As pointed out by Björn in the comment already, it is needed because is a dependent name of the template.

Comment: The problem is that `const_iterator` is a *dependent name* - you can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245.

Comment: "**the** dependent name of the template" is very misleading, `const_iterator` is **a** dependent name.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to output every element, you shouldn't constrain yourself to vectors. The idiomatic, generic solution is to pass two iterators instead:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
void display_contents(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
{
    for (ForwardIterator it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

Then you can use the template with vectors, sets and practically all other containers:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a {2, 3, 5, 7};
    display_contents(a.begin(), a.end());

    std::set<int> b {11, 13, 17, 19};
    display_contents(b.begin(), b.end());
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but noted for future endeavours :)